# How to prevent a page from posting back using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've checked other code, and it looks like I just need to add **return false** to make it work. But, it's not working because it still posts back the page.

```
<asp:Button ID="_btnSearch" Text="Search" 
            onclientclick="CheckForEmptySearchBox()" />

<script type = "text/javascript">
    function CheckForEmptySearchBox() 
    {
        var boxContent = document.getElementById
          ("_ctl0_contentMain__lvTSEntry_ctrl0__txtClientName").value;
        if (boxContent == null || boxContent == "") {
            alert("Please enter search criteria");

            return false;
        }
     }  
</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered using any ASP.NET Validation Controls, specifically [RequiredFieldValdiator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx)?

Comment: Why are you use <asp:button> if you don't want get its onClick on server? Use html button <input type="button" onClick="CheckForEmptySearchBox()">

Comment: @jrummell, I tried but I was having a lot trouble because controls to validate are inside a ListView control. So, the RequiredFieldValue was validating textbox inside every ListViewItem. If you know a better way to isolate the effect of the validation, it'll be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source of onclientclick is receiving `null` rather than `false` because you're not returning the result of the function call.

```
onclientclick="return CheckForEmptySearchBox()"
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. Now I'm just waiting for @jrummell to tell me wheither there's a way to use validation Control inside a ListView without having validation in each row.

Comment: @Richard77. My answer answers your question, but the more appropriate place to put this code is `<form onsubmit="return CheckForEmptySearchBox()">`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a global check on the `Form` and this can be done on code behind as:

```
    if (Page.EnableEventValidation)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"]))
        {
            Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"] = "return CheckForEmptySearchBox();";
        }
    }
```